# How to Filter Coulmns even if a single value in column is not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pycharm

I have a Pandas Dataframe with 500 Rows and 502 Columns, below is the brief outlook of the column names:

```
['cluster', 'question1', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ....,500]
```

Cluster   - Cluster Number
Question1 - Denotes a Text data
columns(0 - 500) - contains cosine similarity values of each of the 500 Questions with one another.

for Every question, I want to filter only those rows which has cosine value > 0.5(lets say x) and < 1 with any other question.

I have Tried the below set of code for filtering the data

```
filter_boolean = final_df[(final_df.iloc[:,2:] > 0.5) &(final_df.iloc[:,2:] < 1)]
```

Expected and Actual result are as per below images[Input DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3rxp.png)
[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VekQl.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas `dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) function uses the `axis` and `how` argument to solve this use case.

To use `dropna` on columns, use `axis=1` (rather than default, `axis=0`, which operates on rows).

To drop where `'any'` are `NaN`, use the `how` keyword and special `'any'`.

This should solve your problem.

You can do this also with boolean filters, but `dropna` may be clearer to read for others and yourself later on.